# Qt regexp on QRect

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qml

I have a QRect which I try to filter in qml using RegExpFilter
QRect(1220,50, 500, 300)

I want to match them like that:
QRect([0-2000], [0-500], *, *)

```
SortFilterProxyModel
{
    onCountChanged: listView.recalculate()
    id: proxyModel
    sourceModel: m_sourceModel
    filters: [
        RegExpFilter {
            enabled: true 
            roleName: "myQRectRole"

            pattern: ????
        }
    ]
}
```

I am stuck as it is a QRect, is it even possible?

(using [SortFilterProxyModel](https://github.com/oKcerG/SortFilterProxyModel) and RegExpFilter)

Comment: what is the meaning of `QRect([0-2000], [0-500], *, *)`? the regex are applied to strings

Comment: The OP means matching anything for arguments 3 and 4 of a QRect (i.e. width / height )

Comment: @AdrienLeravat exactly

Comment: @user215853 So `0-2000` in `QRect([0-2000], [0-500], *, *)` means that the x is between `0 <= x <= 2000`?

Comment: @eyllanesc QRect is defined as QRect(x, y, width , height)
the x position should be between 0-2000 and y 0-500, for widht and height match any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RegExpFilter only serves to filter strings, in your case it is not. The solution is use [ExpressionFilter](https://okcerg.github.io/SortFilterProxyModel/qml-expressionfilter.html):

```
SortFilterProxyModel {
    id: proxyModel
    sourceModel: m_sourceModel
    filters: [
        ExpressionFilter{
            //  QRect([0-2000], [0-500], *, *)
            expression: (model.myQRectRole.x >= 0 && model.myQRectRole.x <= 2000) && (model.myQRectRole.y >= 0 && model.myQRectRole.y <= 500)
        }
    ]
}
```

In the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55200746) there is an example.

Comment: Thank you very much! ExpressionFilter is not in the documentation.
Once I have enough reputation I will up-vote it.
You have a whole lot of cold beverage of your choice.

Comment: @user215853 If it is in the docs (I have put a link as a reference) but there is not an example, maybe if you publish an issue in the repo add it in the future